# No veo las modificaciones que hago sobre node_modules

Tags: vue.js, npm, primevue

El tema es el siguiente:

> Estoy usando el componente Panel de `Primevue`. https://github.com/primefaces/primevue/blob/master/src/components/panel/Panel.vue

Si lo prueban, se darán cuenta que el componente solo se togglea cuando haces click en el boton. Su código es:

```
<template>
    <div :class="containerClass">
        <div class="p-panel-header">
            <slot name="header">
                <span class="p-panel-title" v-if="header" :id="ariaId + '_header'">{{header}}</span>
            </slot>
            <div class="p-panel-icons">
                 <slot name="icons"></slot>
                <button v-if="toggleable" class="p-panel-header-icon p-panel-toggler p-link" @click="toggle" type="button"
                    :id="ariaId +  '_header'" :aria-controls="ariaId + '_content'" :aria-expanded="!d_collapsed" v-ripple>
                    <span :class="{'pi pi-minus': !d_collapsed, 'pi pi-plus': d_collapsed}"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <transition name="p-toggleable-content">
            <div class="p-toggleable-content" v-show="!d_collapsed" role="region" :id="ariaId + '_content'" :aria-labelledby="ariaId + '_header'">
                <div class="p-panel-content">
                    <slot></slot>
                </div>
            </div>
        </transition>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import {UniqueComponentId} from 'primevue/utils';
import Ripple from 'primevue/ripple';

export default {
    name: 'Panel',
    emits: ['update:collapsed', 'toggle'],
    props: {
        header: String,
        toggleable: Boolean,
        collapsed: Boolean
    },
    data() {
        return {
            d_collapsed: this.collapsed
        }
    },
    watch: {
        collapsed(newValue) {
            this.d_collapsed = newValue;
        }
    },
    methods: {
        toggle(event) {
            this.d_collapsed = !this.d_collapsed;
            this.$emit('update:collapsed', this.d_collapsed);
            this.$emit('toggle', {
                originalEvent: event,
                value: this.d_collapsed
            });
        }
    },
    computed: {
        ariaId() {
            return UniqueComponentId();
        },
        containerClass() {
            return ['p-panel p-component', {'p-panel-toggleable': this.toggleable}];
        }
    },
    directives: {
        'ripple': Ripple
    }
}
</script>
```

Ahora bien, yo quiero modificarle ese comportamiento. Quiero que todo el header funcione como el boton, y que al clickear cualquier zona del mismo, el componente se toglee.

En un principio intente llevar la funcion `@click="toggle"` hacia otras etiquetas, pero sin resultado.

Extrañado de ver que nada sucedía, me fui a la funcion `toggle` y le agregué un console en la primer linea. No se imprime.

Cabe aclarar que luego de modificar y salvar `Panel.vue`, desconecto el servidor y lo vuelvo a lanzar, esperando que el cambio se aplique.

Me está faltando algún paso para observar cambios en la carpeta `node_modules`?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Cabe aclarar que si me llevo el componente a mi proyecto, como si fuera un archivo local, este no presenta problemas y funciona a la perfección. Solo tenia que cambiar @click="toggle" del button y llevarlo al header.
El problema es que no levanta los cambios desde node_modules aun habiendo reiniciado el servidor, ventana de incognito y limpiado todos los datos del navegador.

Comment: y no lo va a hacer. el node_modules ademas del codigo, tiene el "compilado" que es el que tu programa esta usando (si no, deberia "compilar" 1 gb cada vez que haces algo)... asi que si tenes un cambio en una libreria, es un buen momento para que lo comentes en esa libreria y hagas el PR que corresponde!

Comment: @gbianchi gracias! qué significa PR? Y que sucede si yo quiero hacer un cambio a algún archivo de ahi? Como debería compilar ese "1 gb" como si fuera la primera vez? con ``npm install``?? (no es algo que haga muy seguido, ir a meter mano a node_modules. Pero necesitaba cambiar el funcionamiento de un plugin, y no creo que sea la última vez que me pase jaja)

Comment: PR = Pull request.. sobre el repositorio de donde sale ese paquete... deberias pedir en el repo que hagan el cambio. No podes cambiar el node_modules, si no deberias (si se puede, depende la licencia) bajarte todo el codigo y hacerlo de tu lado, sin usar la libreria.